# RHEL 6.6: redis-package for php54

Tags: php, rhel6, redis

Redhat Enterprise Linux Server 6 contains `php54` packages, in addition to the normal `php` packages that ship version 5.3.

Unfortunately for me, a `php-redis` package exists, but no `php54-redis` package.

Do I have to compile the extension myself, or are there inofficial repositories that contain the package, or is there another way to get the redis extension for 5.4?

Comment: This right here is why I dislike Software Collections. Try dumping them and using PHP from the remi repository.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing prevents you from installing redis from pecl, like `pecl install redis`.

Comment: this requires me to have all the build tools and dependencies, which I would not like to have on a live server.

Comment: Although I doubt there are reasons for avoiding having gcc/gmake/headers on a production server, you can easily deinstall them after an installation.

Comment: Find a server with the same target architecture.  Install build tools on there.  Build extension.  Deploy to live servers.  Bob's your mother's brother.

Answer (score 1):

Some packages have no version number. Like **php-apc** for example. Try to install it and check the dependencies.

Check the PHP-Version / Dependencies with (you need yum-utils)

```
repoquery --requires php-redis
```

There you can see on which PHP-Version is depends.